# Expandable listview groupview indicator shown in wrong groups

Tags: android

I have group layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="@color/listViewItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGroupName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGroupIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And in my ViewHolder `getGroupView` I do:

```
        if (group.children != null && group.children.size() > 0) {
            if (isExpanded) {
                holder.ivGroupIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
            } else {
                holder.ivGroupIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
            }
        }
```

I have 4 groups with only 2 groups having children. When I expand/collapse various groups, the groups without the children also get an icon displayed.

Is this an Android problem or something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use an `else` section:

```
    if (group.children != null && group.children.size() > 0) {
        if (isExpanded) {
            holder.ivGroupIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
        } else {
            holder.ivGroupIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
        }
    } else {
        holder.ivGroupIcon.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
```